# For each with a dynamic list?

Tags: c#, dynamic, foreach, arraylist

I have a for each loop that runs through the database to check for files that have been flagged for conversion. Currently I have the following code:

```
            /* All files flagged for invidual conversion will be stored in here. */
            ArrayList files = vc.getFilesForInvidualConversion();
            foreach (FileInfoExtended file in files)
            {
                // As long as the status flag hasn't been changed it can continue.
                if (abort == false)
                {
                    if (vc.isFileInUse(file) == false)
                    {
                            // Converting the video file.
                            vc.convertVideoToFLV(file);
                    }
                }
                vc.getFilesForInvidualConversion();
            }
```

In the first line you can see I fill an ArrayList with objects which it will run through with a for each. However, after each file in the list I want to check for possible new files that need to be converted. When I fill the ArrayList again the for each doesn't seem to notice, it keeps working with the original files received from the first line of code. I'd rather want it to update the "files"-ArrayList so that it can convert the new files as well.

Is this possible?

**EDIT:** The anwsers you gave all work for this scenario, but I want to add something. Is it possible to remove a file from the list during the loop? And to make it so it won't convert that one?

**EDIT 2:** This is what I have now:

```
            List<FileInfoExtended> files = vc.getFilesForInvidualConversion();
            while (files.Count > 0)
            {
                if (abort == false)
                {
                    if (vc.isFileInUse(files[0]))
                    {
                        vc.convertVideoToFLV(files[0]);
                    }
                }
                files = vc.getFilesForInvidualConversion();
            }
```

And it works in both cases (when a file is added to the list and when a file is removed from the list). I don't know if it is performance wise a good solution, but right now it suits my needs. Unless there are some issues I'm overlooking?

Any comment will be appreciated!
Kind regards,
Floris

Comment: Try using for and not foreach. foreach relies on the collection not changing during its life.

Comment: I did not know that, that clears up a lot of things! Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a standard 'for' loop.  foreach loops require the collection to be immutable during traversal.  A 'for' loop doesn't have this constraint.  However, getting the ending condition constraints on a 'for' loop might be difficult in this case.

I would consider keeping a list of the files already processed so that when you make you second pass, you can just check to see if you have already handled a particular file.

Comment: I did not know that 'for each' loops work with immutable collections, that clears up a lot of things! Thank you for the information. I think your answer and Paul Keisters will help me I think.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using some other collection instead of `ArrayList`. For example `Stack<T>`. And write smth like this:

```
while (stack.Any())
{
    var item = stack.Pop();
    // convert item
}

// All items were converted
```

At any point you can `stack.Push()` new items.

P.S.: Is there any point using non-generic `ArrayList`?

Comment: At the time of writing the ArrayList I had used another kind of object stored in the ArrayList, I actually simply forgot to correct this, thanks you for the reminder. As for your answer, I will look into all of them and use the one that suits me best.

Comment: It would have suited my needs if it would go the other way around as well but it doesn't. Check my original post edits to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursion passing the index to the recursive function so that you can evaluate your location in the array.

```
void ConvertRecursively(int index, typeForVC vc)
{
   if(abort)
      return;

   ArrayList files = vc.getFilesForInvidualConversion();
   if(index !< files.Count)
       return;

   else 
   {
      if (vc.isFileInUse(files[index]) == false)
       {
           // Converting the video file.
           vc.convertVideoToFLV(files[index]);
       }

       return ConvertRecursive(++index, vc);
   }
}
```

To call just do :

```
ConvertRecursively(0, typeForVC vc);
```

Update: if you need to handle case where the array decreases in size as well, also, the last flow control statement was unnecessary so I took it out:

```
void ConvertRecursively(int index, int prevSize, typeForVC vc)
{
   if(abort)
      return;

   ArrayList files = vc.getFilesForInvidualConversion();
   int sizeDifferential = files.Count <= prevSize ? prevSize - files.Count : 0;

   int adjustedIndex = index - sizeDifferential;

   if(adjustedIndex !< files.Count)
       return;

      if (vc.isFileInUse(files[adjustedIndex]) == false)
       {
           // Converting the video file.
           vc.convertVideoToFLV(files[adjustedIndex]);
       }

       return ConvertRecursive(++adjustedIndex, files.Count, vc);     
}
```

To call just do :

```
ConvertRecursively(0, 0, typeForVC vc);
```

Ok, so now I am just having fun with it. Hopefully it will work for you. I haven't tested this b.t.w.

Comment: It only works when you add files to the list, not when you remove one.

Comment: that can be adjusted, this is just a starting point. Where is the item being removed from the list? it should work  unless it was removed from the list at an index <=  our index variable.

Comment: @Floris, in this (my updated) scenario, as long as the file has not yet been converted and it is removed from the list, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The sane way to do this is to process batches: when each batch is done, get another batch until you hit an empty batch (this is the same approach suggested by @j0rd4n). Here's how you would wrap this logic up in a nice `foreach` loop: first, create the class to manage the iteration:

```
namespace StackOverflow6128549
{
    class FileInfoExtended
    {
        public int PropertyX { get; set; }
    }

    class IncrediblySmartIteration : IEnumerable<FileInfoExtended>
    {
        private List<FileInfoExtended> GetFilesToProcess()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #region IEnumerable<FileInfoExtended> Members

        private IEnumerator<FileInfoExtended> InternalGetEnumerator()
        {
            List<FileInfoExtended> filesToProcess = null;

            do
            {
                filesToProcess = GetFilesToProcess();

                foreach (var fi in filesToProcess)
                {
                    yield return fi;
                }
            }
            while (filesToProcess.Count > 0);
        }

        public IEnumerator<FileInfoExtended> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return InternalGetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable Members

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return InternalGetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

You will then be able to run through objects of this type using a simple `foreach`:

```
        var container = new IncrediblySmartIteration();

        foreach (var fi in container)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fi.PropertyX);
        }
```

Note that you should be concerned with guaranteeing termination when you design the GetFilesToProcess() method. Be sure to think about what will happen when there is an error looking for new files.

Comment: Your method works good for what I asked, thanks. But I notice it doesn't work the other way around. For example, when a file has already been converted by another service. Then I would need to remove that file from the list. But if I test that with this method it still gets converted.